# Is there a way to set DirectByteBuffer memory with JNI?

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

For some reason I have to use Linux-specific API which is not currently accessible from JVM directly and need to design a method which accepts `ByteBuffer` (*This is definitely not because of some performance reason*). Here is how it looks like:

```
//I need to call device-specific ioctl here
//and fill the ByteBuffer
public static native long putIntoByteBuffer(int fd, ByteBuffer buf);
```

The generated header file is

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_net_abcomm_PlatformSpecific_putIntoByteBuffer
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jobject);
```

How to get the `char*` by the given `ByteBuffer` with `JNI`? I could use `DirectBuffer`, but then I will be limited to `DirectBuffer`s only and besides the following warning is generated:

```
warning: DirectBuffer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a 
future release
import sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer;
```

Also there is [`GetDirectBufferAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress) returning `void*` but it is limited to `DirectBuffer`s only.

Comment: There is no way to set non-direct ByteBuffer directly from native. So, you need to have two implementations for direct and heap ByteBuffers and select one of them depending on `ByteBuffer.isDirect`. An implementation for heap ByteBuffer can either use a temporary DirectByteBuffer and then copy data, or get `ByteBuffer.array()` and set the array using JNI `SetByteArrayRegion`.

Comment: Do you really have to put the data into an *existing* `ByteBuffer`?  Would it suffice to create and return a new one, instead?

Comment: One thing you are perhaps missing is that depending on the specific concrete `ByteBuffer` implementation you're working with, there might not *be* any corresponding native array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Actually I am currently inclined to limit the usage to `DirectBuffer`s only and simply throw in case `GetDirectBufferAddress` returns `NULL`. Is such a thing possible and may be appropriate?

Comment: @SomeName, is it *possible*? Sure.  Is it *appropriate*? No.  If the only kind of buffer your method is willing to accept is `sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer`, then that's what the method parameter's type should be.  That would likely require casting on the Java side, but it's *much* easier to debug a `ClassCastException` emitted by your Java code than to debug most any exception emitted by native code.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `GetDirectBufferAddress()` will silently return NULL for a non-direct ByteBuffer, therefore checking `iisDirect()` is necessary.

Comment: @AlexCohn Is it guaranteed that if `isDirect` returns true that `GetDirectBufferAddress` won't return `NULL`.

Comment: **a)** yes, it's guaranteed. **b)** I would still add this extra check. `|||` There is actually nothing you can do with a direct buffer which returns **0** address, not even try to access its bytes in a less efficient way (via an underlying array, or with `get()`). This would be a clear evidence of a corrupt buffer object. But it's so easy to safeguard against this specific kind of corruption.

Comment: Note that instead of `CallBooleanMethod( javaBuf, GetMethodID( FindClass( "java/nio/ByteBuffer" ), "isDirect", "()Z" ) )` you can use `IsInstanceOf ( javaBuf,FindClass ( "java/nio/DirectByteBuffer" ) )`

Comment: Actually, the [Java7 spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress) requires that for non-direct buffer, `GetDirectBufferAddress` returns `NULL`, but Android modern JVM (ART) is not compliant. I have opened a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121463764) about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that you limit yourself to public classes and their public API, you have two relatively efficient alternatives for approaching the problem, but they have in common that they rely on putting the data into a Java `byte[]`.  That's not so hard:

```
/* error checks omitted for brevity; these are *not* optional */

char *cBytes = /* ... */;
size_t numCBytes = /* ... */;
jbyteArray javaBytes = /* ... */;

jsize numBytes = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, javaBytes);
jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, javaBytes, NULL);
/* It is pretty safe to assume that jbyte is a character type, such as signed
   char, in any C implementation that supports the JNI at all */
/* Assumes numCBytes <= numBytes; adjust as necessary if that may not be true: */
memcpy(bytes, cBytes, numCBytes);
(*env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(env, javaBytes, bytes, 0);
```

Note that if the JNI function performs some kind of I/O to get the bytes, it may be able to read them directly into `bytes` (depending on the native requirements, not on JNI), but in that case you should use the non-`Critical` versions of the `Get`/`Release` routines.

With that said, your two main alternatives for getting the data all the way into a `ByteBuffer` are

- if the buffer `hasArray()`, then obtain the `byte[]` for the above procedure via the buffer's `array()` method.  Done and done.
- if the buffer does not `hasArray()`, or if you don't want to check, then obtain the `byte[]` by instantiating it freshly, and after loading it via the above procedure, copy the contents into the buffer via the buffer's bulk `put(byte[])` or `put(byte[], int, int)` method.  Obviously, this involves an extra copy relative to the other alternative, and it uses an extra temporary object.

I cannot recommend assuming a specific concrete `ByteBuffer` subclass or relying on non-public methods.  That might be worth considering if performance were a high priority, but you seem to say it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the thing that I did not understand yet was why should not the array methods be crtitical? I need to communicate with a device driver that provides `ioctl`s I need (i.e. it involves some io anyway)

Comment: @SomeName, using the `*PrimitiveArrayCritical()` routines provide your best chance to avoid *internal* copying between Java and native arrays, but there is a price: if you're using those then the code between the Get and Release must complete quickly, must not block, and must not call other JNI functions.  If you're using `ioctl`s to populate the array, then the `Critical` versions are right out.  You want `GetByteArrayElements()` and `ReleaseByteArrayElements()`, which provide the same interface.

Comment: No matter what you do, the system call will only work with native memory. What the JVM does is create/caches a direct ByteBuffer as needed, read the data and copy it into an on heap ByteBuffer. You can write something to do basically that in JNI, or just do it into Java.